# Is there any reason to use the support.v4 library in Android?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've been working on an app that is targeting Android 4.0 and above with no plans of supporting earlier versions. Is there any good reasons for me to continue using the support library?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are a number of [features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) unique to the support library that apply to all API levels:

- [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) - Allows applications to easily register for and receive intents within a single application without broadcasting them globally.
- [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) - Adds a ViewGroup that manages the layout for the child views, which the user can swipe between.
- [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) - Adds support for creating a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) that can be pulled in from the edge of a window.
- [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) - Adds widget for creating linked summary and detail views that appropriately adapt to various screen sizes.
- [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) - Adds support for sharing of private files between applications.

And others such as

- [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) - Helper for the common pattern of implementing a BroadcastReceiver that receives a device wakeup event and then passes the work off to a Service, while ensuring that the device does not go back to sleep during the transition.
- [AtomicFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/AtomicFile.html) - for atomic operations on a file
- [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) - adds pull to refresh to a view

Also note that some newer features, such as [nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) (which were added only in Android 4.2) are available in the support library versions of Fragments. [Renderscript intrinics](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#Renderscript) were also only introduced in Android 4.2 and important if you are doing things such as real time image processing. [Big style notifications and notification actions](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Notifications) (introduced in Android 4.1) are much easier to work with when using [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) (and the [Android Wear Notification API](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html) is built on it).

Comment: Wow, didn't realize the support library brought in all those features. Thanks! I also discovered in the last hour that it also includes the [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) library, which is needed for building notification below API level 16.

Comment: Once again Android proves itself to be counter intuitive.  I really wish all this mess was handled under the hood instead of having it's api users suffer the consequences of their convoluted libraries.

Comment: @AndrewS - I'd love to hear your suggestions for better systems! There's unfortunately only so many ways to deliver new functionality to old platform levels other than to provide a library not tied to API level.

Comment: Yes, but there exists much incompatibility in the compatibility libraries.  For example android.support.v4.xxxx libraries can not be mixed with the more native android.app counter parts. For example a list view fragment from the non support libraries cannot be casted to one from the support libraries.  Sometimes Android Studio exacerbates this with the wizards choosing the support libraries, and the RightClick>New>Fragment> plain fragment using the native ones. Some newer components are only in the support library.  I can see now why Google needed Gradle to automate it's builds, it is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of use support v4 (as far as I know):

1. You can use ViewPager (it only exists in support v4)
2. You can use ArrayMap (added in API 19)

Answer (score 0):

You can use android-support-v13 if your minSdkVersion is >=13. The jar is in $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v13

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes it does provide the answer. 
There's no reason to use support.v4 if your minSdkVersion>=13, you should use support.v13 in that case.