# Are support libraries needed at all for apps with minimum SDK of 15+?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create an Android app that uses the ViewPager way of navigating between screens and I don't want to support any device below SDK 15 because I don't want to have to worry about anything support library-related.  But when I create a new project using the wizard in Android Studio for a ViewPager interface with a minimum SDK of 15, I get a template that includes:

```
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

The main activity includes these two member variables that come from these support libraries:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
```

Is there another way to setup a "pager" style interface with a minimum SDK of 15 that doesn't require any support libraries?  Because if I need to include the support libraries for this functionality, then I might as well support SDK 11 and higher instead.

Comment: AFAIK things like viewpager are only in the support library. I think it's dumb to have to use a library with a ton of stuff you're never going to use, but that's just me. It's also poor that the library does not have preference fragments.

Comment: There are a [ton of reasons to use the support library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363)