# Do I need the compatibility library for ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator()?

Tags: android

I want to use ActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable), but it's only available from api 18 onwards:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

It seems available in the compatibility library from v7 onwards?:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

I'm not using any of the compatibility libraries, though, since I was targeting only api 14 and higher. Reading this article I thought that was ok to do:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

So now do I have to restructure everything to use the compatibility library and have all my activities extend from ActionBarActivity? Please let it be no.

Thanks

Comment: But there's [lots that you get only in the support library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363) - and you don't want any of that?

Answer (score 1):

While the main reason to use the compatibility library is to run on pre-11 versions, there are always new features added and the compatibility library also addresses those differences.  For example, there's a bunch of features that were added in 14 but not in 11, the compatibility library backports those to 11 as well as 7.

Since this feature is v18+ only, if you want to use it, you have to use the compatibility library.  Or just drop the feature.