# Replacement for FragmentStatePagerAdapter from support library

Tags: android

I am trying to get rid of android support library by setting min SDK to 14. 
However, I cannot find a replacement for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in Android 14 SDK to be used instead. What adapter should I use?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager` and their associated `PagerAdapter`s (including `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) are only available as part of the support library as are [many other features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363).

Comment: So basically I have to stick to support library and there's no way to completely get rid of it?

Comment: If anything, you should consider using it more - it provides important APIs to every version of Android that users come to expect (tabs without the ability to swipe between then feel broken, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's not way to get rid of the support-v4 package completely, but when you create a new project in Android Studio, auto-generated code uses support-v13 library. So I decided to stick to it as well.