# Activity with Tabs without using Support Library?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, tabs, android-support-library

I have a project that uses the support v4 library for an activity with tabs navigation.
My app have a min sdk of 14 (ICS), and i want to remove all the references to the support v4 library.
Is there a way to achieve the tab navigation using only classes of the android.app.* package instead of android.app.v4.*?

Comment: Try to remove the support_v4.jar from libs folder. use ctrl+shift+o for automatic imports in eclipse. first backup your project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer about features unique to the support library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363), [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (what enables swiping between tabs) is **only** found in the Support Library.

In addition, as mentioned in the [Tabs and ViewPager guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ), tabs that match the [material design specs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html) are only found in [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), which in turn requires Support v4.