# Compatibility implications of using native Fragment versus app support version?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can either use the app support library version of Fragments or the native one. If I use the native one what percent of devices will I not be able to support? I'm confused by the graph at https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html since my understanding is that native Fragments came in for Honeycomb but that isn't shown in the chart.

Comment: Honeycomb isn't in the chart because it's under 1% or whatever the cutoff is.  It existed briefly on one generation of tablets, and then the next generation all came with 4.x.  The reason 2.x is still big is because it was shipping on the majority of budget phones until about a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Honeycomb](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0-highlights.html) is Android 3.0 therefore anything at or above 3.0 (such as Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean, KitKat, etc) all have support for native fragments. Note that [nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) (i.e., fragments within fragments) were only added in Android 4.2 but are included in the support library version of Fragments.

As there are a lot of [Android Support Library unique features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363) that you should be using, there's no penalty for using the support library version of Fragments and some UI libraries, such as [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) (which simplifies support for the Action Bar and theming across all versions of Android), assume you are using the support library versions.

Comment: The reason I'm looking at native is because PreferenceFragment isn't supported in the app support library. So basically I will lose Gingerbread? I'm still unsure on implications.

Comment: Preferences are a totally different thing and, you're right, the compatibility support there is not very good there. Personally, I would special case Preferences entirely, either not using `PreferenceFragment` at all (you can just use `PreferenceActivity` and `addPreferencesFromResource` from there, even if it is deprecated) or building both a Gingerbread specific Preferences Activity and a Honeycomb+ Preferences Activity (that uses `PreferenceFragment`s). In either case though, you wouldn't have a choice on whether to use support library or regular fragments.