# Is it safe to use android.app.Fragment while using compatibility library

Tags: android, android-support-library

My new project is gonna be of API 14 min level. I'm going to use the compatibility library because it holds a lot of [cool stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740300/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-support-v4-library-in-android/22740525#22740525). Wouldn't I bump into any compatibility issues if I use **android.app.Fragment** instead of **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**?

I don't want to use the later because I would like to use new (Honeycomb) animation framework to animate fragments transition (and to use FragmentManager from SDK), for instance. Just afraid it wouldn't work with some components from the compatibility lib where **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** must be used.

Comment: You should not have issues as long as you don't mix imports, and even though you'll get a compile time error

Comment: not everything is included in the framework, viewpager is not a part of the framework, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wouldn't I bump into any compatibility issues if I use android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Not generally. Use the `v13` version of the base library, not the `v4` one, so that you can pick up `v13` editions of classes like `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which will work with the native API Level 11+ edition of fragments.

Comment: I looked into v13 and it doesn't seem to contain all 'cool stuff' from as v4 does. Like ViewPager, for example. Does it mean I would probably need to use both of them?

Comment: @Eugene: "I looked into v13 and it doesn't seem to contain all 'cool stuff' from as v4 does" -- yes, it does. The `support.v13` *Java package* does not contain duplicates of everything. The `v13` *JAR* contains all of the `support.v4` classes and the `support.v13` classes.