# What value is there in supporting Android version 2.2 and lower?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently if I want to support fragments on older versions of Android such as 2.2 and lower I have to extend to FragmentActivity instead of Activity. Which means I have to add the FragmentActivity library to my Project. I'm just curious of the value in this, is it worth supporting lower than 2.2?

Comment: There's [quite a few features](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363) you only get from the Support Library even for modern versions of Android.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your target audience. For example I looked at my stats for the oldest app on the market I have and it shows that I still have old installs but these are about 1.6% of all my users (v 2.2 and older). Based on that I would simply go with multiple APK builds so my old customers can still download old version if they want to their ancient devices but I would do all my new development for newer version.

Comment: Note: if you increase your min SDK for a new production release, you implicitly turn on multiple APKs - users will always get the newest production version that is compatible with their device.