# DrawerLayout: Not part of android.jar?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

By Using `DrawerLayout` (by using `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`)from Android support library, we are achieving the navigation drawer functionality in our Android app.

But this is the ***ONLY*** thing an app needs from `android.support.v4`.

Is there a way or a roadmap in future exist, where `DrawerLayout` becomes part of `android.jar`(like Fragment who migrated from support-library now into android.jar)?

This way developers are not required to add a library(`android.support.v4`) just for using 1 widget/class from it!

Also, Currently, is there a way to continue using `DrawerLayout` without a need to add `android.support.v4`? 
 App does not have a requirement to use other Navigation patterns like Toolbar or ViewPager.

Comment: "Currently, is there a way to continue using DrawerLayout without a need to add `android.support.v4`?" - Sure. Pull the class and any dependencies from the source code directly. There are at least 7 other classes you'll need to grab, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [large amount of functionality being unique to support-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363), most of the components in that library will remain there long term as it allows continual bug fixes and evolving of those components to meet the latest design and functionality specs without leaving broken versions in older versions of the framework. If you are using [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) (either directly or via the gradle `minifyEnabled` line), parts of the support library you are not using will be completely stripped from your application.

Of course, you can certainly extract `DrawerLayout` from the library and embed it in your application: the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java) is readily available if you find it necessary.

Comment: We do use ProGuard for obfuscation and stripping, I am concerned about the APK Size (as app is bulky in graphics and drawables). Just by using "required" class, as you said, is perhaps way forward for us. So, will `DrawerLayout` be never part of `android.jar`? In Future...of course?

Comment: I'd never say never, but I'd not bet on it.