# Details on on Android Libraries

Tags: android, performance, memory, android-support-library

Good day!

I am a newbie to Android programming, and by being the curious animal that i am, there are a few things that i would like to know about the Android libraries, the support libraries to be specific, i did my homework(google) and found some answers but they are either old or unclear;

• How significant is performance hit inflicted by the support library if any?

• I hear that using support library makes your app, memory hogs. is this that bad when developing memory intensive apps (etc image-processing/signal-processing)?

• Let's say I'm completely ignoring any Android below 4.2, is it possible to make a "Support-library free" application? or rather, is there a corresponding alternative native Class or mechanism for every support library class or mechanism(ex. ViewPager)?

• And with regards to later support libraries(ex. V7), are they cumulative or they just add new features?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Support Library includes a [large amount of unique functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363) that is not found elsewhere - this includes elements such as `ViewPager`. [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), for example, is one of the few ways to get a consistent look to your app between pre-5.0 and 5.0+ devices (where 5.0 changed to [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html)).

There is **little to no** performance impact when using the Support Library. There is, of course, an increase in the size of your APK which can be countered for the most part by using [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to strip out unused classes in addition to [shrinkResources](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/eHsStybrrBf) to remove unused bitmaps.

I'd suggest reading through the [full list of features](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) or watching the [Support Library overview video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PIc-DuEU2s) to better understand what is in each library and why you might want to use each.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so the support library is no longer a "support library", this is quite confusing, however, if i ever find a native variant of certain class should i prefer using it(native)? and with regards to ViewPager, i've seen something on it's documentation regarding it being old and there's already built in functionality akin to that.

Comment: Yes, it is best to think of it as platform features not tied to any API level - the support name is a legacy of its beginning more than anything else. You should always use the support library versions if both a native and support library version appears - the support library versions always get the latest fixes while devices stuck on older versions of Android may be stuck with bugs. Specific to `ViewPager`, there is no built in equivalent functionality.

Comment: Thanks!, so "support" is just a historic leftover... i have already asked this in my question, but does the use of support library use more memory versus the native ones?

Comment: For those features that have both framework and support versions, they're basically the same memory wise.