# Doing an Android sliding drawer without the support APIs

Tags: android

I'd like to add a sliding drawer to my app which is using the min sdk version of 16 and a target sdk of 21 and should allow it to use the most recent features of the platform.

I looked around on how to implement a sliding drawer, and all the articles I found talk about using some support APIs to do just that.

My app is not yet using these support APIs.

I wonder if implementing the sliding drawer is possible without any support APIs, and if so, if there is any resources showing just that.

Comment: support API is not just for old devices. It also brings lollipop design to pre-21 version, as well as various widgets that are quite useful.

Comment: "I wonder if implementing the sliding drawer is possible without any support APIs" -- by definition, yes. After all, not only were the support libraries written by ordinary programmers, but there are third-party libraries implementing drawers that were written by ordinary programmers. Implementing such a drawer yourself will require thousands of lines of code, as you can tell by looking at the source for other drawer implementations. Most developers are better off using an existing drawer implementation, rather than writing yet another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html), the basis for [Creating a Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) is only found in the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4) (along with [many other Support Library only APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363)). There is nothing in the Android framework that provides this same functionality.

To provide the most consistent experience to users, you should just use the Support Library.

Comment: I'd like to use the 22.2.0 version of the support API but my Android SDK android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux.tar only has the 22.0.0 version. I wonder where can I find it.

Comment: @StephaneEybert - you have to update the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository from the SDK Manager.

Comment: I updated my Android with the sdk manager, but still, Eclipse cannot find the NavigationView class even though the manager says it has the Android Support Library 22.2.1 as installed.

Comment: Now I looked into the programs/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/ directory and it listed the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar and android-support-v4.jar archives.
It's too bad the files themselves don't show any version number. I unpacked one such archive to see if there was a version file somewhere but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using support APIs, but if you really dont want to, you can use user-created library.

Here's one I used for one of my projects:

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is always possible. However, the `DrawerLayout` class is available only in support libraries.

When I first realized that, it made no sense to me. But now I see support libraries as an extension of the core libraries (`android.*`).

Anyway, I recommend using the support libraries or you will have to create the logic to do exactly the same from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android design support library, it's working on all devices in android and it's open source so you can edit it as you like with custom element.

Here's a reference [how to implement Navigation drawer using new android support library](http://androidgifts.com/navigation-view-using-design-support-library/)

Comment: You'd know where I can find the 22.2.0 version of the support API ? The latest SDK android-sdk_r24.3.3-linux.tar only has the 22.0.0 version.

Comment: How did you tried to import it ? did you use build.gradle file ?

Comment: No, I've not used gradle at all. I'm doing a Maven project. I wonder where does gradle find the libraries. If only I could just manually download them. But where are they...

Comment: I prefer to use build.gradle file just copy and paste this code in it and it'll download it, the manual way is to download the SDK from andoridStudio website

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}`

Comment: Let me know if it helped please or try to explain your problem deeply

Comment: I ran the command: android sdk to update the sdk to 22 and it downloaded and installed the libraries. The Android 5.1.1 platform us installed. The Android Support Library 22.2.1 is installed. But Eclipse won't find the NavigationView class that I need.

Comment: aha, you are using eclipse then, my example was using Android studio and i'm really recommending that you switch to android studio because eclipse is not officially supported by Android dev team Google any more.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to stick to Eclipse. I don't like to buy corralled into places for no valid reason. specially when the decision is made by company relocating to the state of Delaware... Cheers anyway.