# Use CoordinatorLayout or equivalent framework widget with minSdkVersion 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm going to create an application with minSdkVersion 21.
I removed all support libraries but I can't find anything equivalent of android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.
Shoud I activate the design library even knowing that it will be never installed on devices with api which is lower than 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shoud I activate the design library even knowing that it will be never installed on devices with api which is lower than 21?

If you want to use `CoordinatorLayout`, yes. Moreover, AFAIK, that will require you to fully implement `appcompat-v7` (e.g., inherit from `AppCompatActivity`, use a `Theme.AppCompat`-based theme).

Eventually, perhaps someone will forward-port elements out of this library to work without the `appcompat-v7` dependency.

Comment: I am using Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar and i have extended Activity class.
Maybe I did not understand the meaning of support libraries.
They also have unique features or are only for backward compatibility?

Comment: @keyz: Much of what is in the collection of support libraries constitutes "unique features". In some cases, those unique features have dependencies on things like `appcompat-v7`, and in some cases they do not. Based on my testing to date, everything in the Design Support Library requires `appcompat-v7`, usually for trivial reasons.

Comment: @keyz - The Support Library does [a lot of unique things even in Support v4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740525/1676363), not even counting [all of the other Support Libraries built on top of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PIc-DuEU2s)

Answer (score 1):

There is no framework equivalent to the Design Library. You'll need to include the Design Library if you want to use any of the functionality contained within.